# Can you tell me how to write it better or correctly?

Tags: postgresql

I have three tables **(№1, №2, №3)** and I want to make a summary. In table №1, data is recorded and then compared with table №2, and if there were differences in at least one of the columns, then he writes it to table №3.  And if not, then nothing. After checking, table №1 becomes the place №2. and table №2 is deleted or overwritten.

First question, how can this be done?

Second question, what should I write to the table so that the data is overwritten and not added in a new way?*

I use postgresql 14 If it is not clear, I can draw a diagram

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (id bigserial primary key, a text);
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE table2 (id bigserial primary key, b text);
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE table3 (id bigserial primary key, c text);
CREATE TABLE
INSERT INTO table3 (id,c) (SELECT table1.id, a FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON (table1.id) = (table2.id)  WHERE (table1.a) <> (table2.b));
UPDATE table2 SET b = c FROM table3 WHERE table2.id = table3.id;
```

You could probably combine the statements above into a CTE or INSERT ... RETURNING.  Left as an exercise for the OP.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work as it should. For example, I don't need to check find, but I need to find columns will always be different and then the query will think that there is a difference